# My Access is duplicating my reports in print preview and creating an excess amount of pages to print

Tags: ms-access-2016

I currently have multiple reports set up in a navigation form. I have a button set up on these reports to show a print preview of the report before printing, however whenever I select to preview the report within the navigation form I get an excess of pages that would like to print with this form. The print preview button works fine outside of the navigation form and only displays one copy of the report. Is there any way to get this print preview button to work properly inside the navigation pane.

The macro is a simple print preview macro. RunMenuCommand  Command: PrintPreview

Comment: Use VBA: `DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportName", acViewPreview`

Comment: Im not really sure what that is supposed to look like in VBA